# Can I put concrete over PVC pipe?

Tags: plumbing, concrete, floor, drain, pvc

I have my laundry room in the backyard and there is an area that had a thin piece of concrete and below it there is soil. Beneath the soil there lies the drainage PVC 1 ½” pipe, gas line (not currently connected to anything), and water line for the washing machine. I had to dig out the soil a bit and replace a section of en exposed PVC pipe that was broken. The PVC pipe is the thin type. I replaced the damaged section with Schedule 40.

I want to cover up the soil with cement to flush the floor. This will need about 4 inches of concrete (Height) in an area of about 8 inches by 10 feet.

I was thinking of using a [concrete mix](http://www.quikrete.com/ProductLines/CrackResistantConcrete.asp).
I live in an all year warm climate, BTW.

Is it ok to pour the concrete over the compacted soil and not worry that the weight will crush the PVC pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Schedule 40 pipe is what is used under many of our slabs and under the driveways for conduits/pathways for future use. Never had an issue. Schedule 35, yes, it would crush.
Make sure the conduit is at least flush with the sub grade or it will act as a control joint and the concrete will crack at the place the pipe is.